# How to remove all the existing highlight markers in ace editor using react

Tags: reactjs, latex, highlight, ace-editor, react-ace

I am using ace editor and I am highlighting lines by defining this code:

```
var Range = ace.require('ace/range').Range;
editor.session.addMarker(new Range(item - 1, 0, item - 1, 1), "warning-marker", "fullLine");
```

Now I want to remove all the markers that I have used in my editor considering I don't have any marker id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I solved the issue finally:

```
const prevMarkers = editor.session.getMarkers();
if (prevMarkers) {
  const prevMarkersArr = Object.keys(prevMarkers);
  for (let item of prevMarkersArr) {
    editor.session.removeMarker(prevMarkers[item].id);
  }
}
```